# How to pass image, from uiimagepickercontroller, into another scene's uiimageview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I save a `UIImagePickerController` camera image so I can send to `CreateViewController` scene's `UIImageView`?

`HomeViewController`(scene 1) has a button that loads `UIImagePickerController` and returns with an image from the camera. `CreateViewController`(scene 2) has an empty `UIImageView`.

**HomeViewController.h**

```
#import "CreateViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *myImage;

- (IBAction)cameraImage:(id)sender;
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
@implementation HomeViewController
@synthesize imagePicker, myImage;

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"create"]) {
    CreateViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIImage *image = myImage;
    cvc.myImage = image;

}
}

//Camera button action
- (IBAction)cameraImage:(id)sender{
//UIImagePickerController space in memory
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
//Set the delegate
imagePicker.delegate = self;
//Set the sourceType
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//Show Image Picker UI
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{}];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:    (NSDictionary *)info {

self.myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"create" sender:self];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

**CreateViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bgImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *myImage;
```

**CreateViewController.m**

```
@implementation CreateViewController
@synthesize bgImage, myImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIImage *image = myImage;
[bgImage setImage:image];
}
```

Download sample code here; http://code-blind.com/ios6-camera-picture-to-another-scenes-uiimageview/

Comment: I would save it in an UIImage object and pass it to the new view controller in prepareForSegue. How exactly did you do that (show some relevant code) and what exactly is your problem (Some debug data/NSLog ...) ?

Comment: Can you post your code with the `UIImagePickerDelegate` methods, your `HomeViewController`'s `prepareForSegue` and the header file for your `DisplayViewController`?

Comment: "save it in an UIImage object and pass it to the new view controller in prepareForSegue" I will try this again and post my code.

Comment: Like I said I would, in previous comment, added code to my original post. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably your bgImage wasn't initialized correctly because in -viewDidLoad, the *image was nil. Try editing your prepareForSegue method like: `cvc.bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];`

Comment: Problem solved! I wasn't targeting the property on the destination VC. See edited post and link to code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a segue is not mandatory if you are instanciating the controller programmatically.

The easiest way to achieve that is something like

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage * pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    DisplayViewController * controller = [DisplayViewController new];
    controller.imageView.image = pickedImage;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

If you want to use a segue you need to manually invoke it by doing

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your-segue-name" sender:self];
```

then you can use an ivar in your HomeViewController to store the `pickedImage` and pass it to your `destinationViewController`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {    
    DisplayViewController * controller = (DisplayViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.imageView.image = _pickedImage;
}
```

where `_pickedImage` is the ivar where you stored the image after it has been picked.

Comment: you are doing everything almost ok, until the `viewDidLoad` of `CreateViewController`. You don't need the `myImage` there since you are already assigning the image to `bgImage` in `prepareForSegue:sender:`

Comment: Also you should declare your property as `strong` as opposed to `retain`.

Comment: What do I need in `viewDidLoad`? I edited retain to strong. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You should not do anything there since you already set the bgImage before pushing the controller

Comment: Okay we did it, after trying for two days, here's the code; http://code-blind.com/stackoverflow-appOne-Archive.zip.

Comment: I'm glad that you made it.

Comment: Be careful, you cannot do this: controller.imageView.image = _pickedImage; Because you cannot guarantee that imageView has been initialized yet (probably not ...). You should just have controller.image = _pickedImage, and when the controller's image is set, you update the imageView.

Answer (score 1):

On ur first view

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    CreateViewController* sI = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"XXXXX"];
    sI.myImage = image;
}
```

XXXXX is identifier of view.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be sure that your delegate method is called and that you have the image.
Next, store the image to a property:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {


    self.takenImage = image; // assuming you have declared @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *takenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"my-segue" sender:self];   
    }];

}
```

After that, this method's being called:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // you need to set the picked image to the controller:

    DisplayViewController *controller; // get the controller
    controller.image = self.takenImage;
}
```

Comment: This is really a bad practice since you're messing with the semantics of the method. `sender` is meant to be the object that initiated the segue not a random parameter.

Comment: Correct, that's why I've written it's a hacky method, but it's the quickest way to get it running. I'll improve the code example

Comment: How to store as property then send?

Comment: quick does not necessarily mean dirty. Now it's better even though using a segue is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

in this code:

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     

      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
     {
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];


 if( i ==1)
 {

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^
      {
          Second_ViewController*secondview=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second_ViewController"];
          secondview.bb_image=image;
          [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ]setInteger:0 forKey:@"123"];

          [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];

      }];
 }
```