# more details about how persistent store coordinator work?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

why persistent store coordinator notify when any of associate context is saved in persistent store

the second question

Who is receiving these notification

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO , this topic has been addressed a lot on this site. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574533/how-to-get-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-and-pass-to-next-vc and related questions for more clues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get image from UIImagePickerController and Pass to next VC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574533/how-to-get-image-from-uiimagepickercontroller-and-pass-to-next-vc)

Comment: hi i could not see the answer to my problem in Any post